# No Pipeline Diagrams in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created 2 pipelines using the Copy data wizard, but neither show up when I click on the Diagram action.  I get the message "This factory contains no pipelines or datasets".  The pipelines both run successfully, and do show up when clicking on Pipelines blade.  Both pipelines were configured as One time.  Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Monitor & Manage view for Azure Data Factory does not currently show the diagram for "run once" (aka oneTime or once-only) pipelines, as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#onetime-pipeline):

> Diagram view does not show one-time pipelines. This behavior is by
>   design.

Reconfigure with a schedule that has only one slice if you really want to see it.  However you can view still the progress (or otherwise) of the activity by clicking 'Refresh' on the 'Activity Windows' section in the lower part of that pane, click your pipeline then progress appears on the right-hand side eg

[image: Monitoring pane]

Comment: I have the opposite issue, everything shows in the upper panel but the activity windows is empty.

Comment: @Ernesto Check the Datasets section in the portal to see if any are pending or errored.

Comment: I figured I think my filtering was off. After changing dates and looking at the activity level I can see the windows. Now my problem is different as a pretty much empty custom activity just stays in Running
(0% complete) for ever, but I will create a question for it.