# Can't see activities in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline which contains 4-5 copy activity.It is scheduled to run only "one time". After deploying the pipeline, it doesn't show any activity in activities list.
If I change the scheduling of pipeline to "scheduled" then I can see the activities in activity list.
Please help me. I want to execute the pipeline only once. But It is not showing the activities.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897080/no-pipeline-diagrams-in-azure-data-factory

Comment: Does it mean that even if it is not showing me the activities, the activities will run? But I have created one another pipeline using copy wizard and it is executed successfully. Still, I can see the activities in that pipeline.

Comment: Yes they will run.  If you read through the article linked to in my answer, it states this behaviour is "by design".  Consider upvoting that answer and deleting this question as it looks like a duplicate.

Comment: I would like to give it a shot first. If it works fine then I'll consider it as a duplicate question. :(

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer that we can see one slice of the pipeline. In my case, I can't see any slice. My activity window is completely empty. I checked my datasets too but I couldn't find any error there.